# Why does FileInputReader.read() only reads 5 bytes at a time (Java)?

Tags: java, byte, java-io, indexoutofboundsexception, fileinputstream

OK, so I've been trying to read a ("any") binary file to a byte[] array using FileInputReader.read()...But no matter the file length it only reads 5 bytes at a time...
(btw im using udp to send the array/file)

```
byte[] array_bytes = new byte[1024];

while((nread=file.read(array_bytes))!=-1){

            number_bytesread += array_bytes.length;
            socket_udp.send(send_package);

            count += 1;
        }
```

-send_package is a datagrampacket using array_bytes to send the message

I've tried to use the function read(byte[], offset, lenght), but if I put the lenght over 5, it occurs this error, at the first time reading, even thought the file is surely bigger than 5 bytes:

```
nread=file.read(array_bytes, 0, 1024);
```

no need for offset since i send immediatly after reading.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
at udp_server2.UDP_Server2.Send_Udp(UDP_Server2.java:122)
at udp_server2.UDP_Server2.main(UDP_Server2.java:77)
Java Result: 1
```

Thanks in advance for the help,
André

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your array length isn't *actually* 1024. I know you've shown code creating it with 1024 bytes, but I suspect your actual code either changes the value somewhere else, or that it's created in a different way.

It would be helpful if you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, but failing that, the first diagnostic step I'd take would be to look at `array_bytes.length`, either in the debugger or via logging. I strongly suspect that you'll find it's 5. Once you've established that, you need to work out *why* it's 5, which has nothing to do with the calls to reading from the input stream.

Also note that this line is fundamentally wrong:

```
number_bytesread += array_bytes.length;
```

It should be:

```
number_bytesread += nread;
```

... because you've just read `nread` bytes. You're also sending `send_package` which appears to have nothing to do with the data you've just read.

Additionally, I suggest you start following Java naming conventions, with things like `arrayBytes` rather than `array_bytes`. (I'd just use `buffer` or `data`, mind you - but I'm pointing out that variable and names in Java are typically camelCased rather than using_underscores_for_word_breaks.)

Comment: that line indeed proves that the array length is indeed 5..    number_bytesread+= array_bytes.length; about the naming conventions, its my first time coding Java and my first time using Stackoverflow (this answer will be well formated indeed...). Im using c naming convention seems thats the only language i used to code in.. thanks ill try to understand why byte[] array_enviar = new byte[1024]; has the warning "the value is never used"

Comment: @Andre: Well that suggests you're not using that variable - you're using a different one. Check everything carefully, including casing! In terms of naming conventions, one benefit of learning and following the convention of a new language while you're learning it is that it reinforces the message that it *is* a different language, with different idioms etc.